# android button text under crossed (wrong symbol) image

Tags: android, image, button, text

I would like to add an image over the text in a button. If I add the image as background of the button it is getting added below the text. Expected result is added as an image. Please help

[image: Text below the image]

**Update:**
I need to do this programatically.

Comment: Add a TextView and ImageView inside a FrameLayout

Answer (score 1):

In XML,

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container">*
    <TextView ...></TextView> <!-- Your A text -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

In code,

```
RelativeLayout container = (Rel...) findViewById(R.id.container);
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
// Set Image View params and image and add it programmatically
container.addView(imgView);
```

Comment: Thanks as requested I wanted to have it in a button.